# Slick Carousel - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

```
1. $(document).ready(function(){
2. $('.fade').slick({
3.  dots: true,
4.   infinite: true,
5.   speed: 500,
6.   fade: true,
7.   slide: '> div',
9.   cssEase: 'linear'
10. });
11.});
```

The code above is from Slick Courseal, I am new to JQuery and JS, the web console (Chrome Developer tools) throw this error at line 2. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I followed the Directions at http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, the fade example and its throwing this same error when I run this script. I copied and pasted the example code, but doesn't get through. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or why its throwing that error? Did the guy who made slick messed up in his code?

Comment: Do you have an element with the class fade?

Comment: Yeah I do ( I believe ) its in this code

<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<div id="slider" class="fade">
      <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]"/></div>
          <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]"/></div>
      <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]"/></div>
      <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]"/></div>
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same error, turns out the version of jQuery was pretty outdated. So try upgrading it. :)